# Deleting an object in Ruby

Tags: ruby, garbage-collection, finalizer

Let's say I have the following class:

```
class Vehicle
    @@total_vehicles = 0
    @@all_instances = Array.new

    def initialize
        @@total_vehicles += 1
        @@all_instances << self
    end

    def total_vehicles #returns total number of Vehicles 'alive'
        return @@total_vehicles
    end

    def all_vehicles #returns an array of all Vehicle objects
        return @@all_instances
    end

end
```

Now to keep `@@total_vehicles` and `@@all_instances` up-to-date and correct, I want to make sure that they are correctly decremented and updated, respectively, when one of those objects is garbage collected. But here is what happens:

```
v = Vehicle.new
Vehicle.total_vehicles # => 1
v = nil #no references to Vehicle instance now
ObjectSpace.garbage_collect #instance garbage collected
Vehicle.total_vehicles # => 1    Nope!
```

Well I could add a finalizer Proc to each instance of the Vehicle class that, when called upon the object's garbage collection, would be called. But according to the documentation, `ObjectSpace.define_finalizer(v,someProc)` would call someProc *after* the Vehicle instance is destroyed - meaning I cannot use `self` or `self.class` in there (since there would be no class, as there is no object!) I could have the proc call a public accessor method on the Vehicle class, but that takes away the purpose of class variables being accessible only to the class and its instances -> essentially turning the class variables into gvars.

How can I have the equivalent of a destructor method (from C++) that will get a Vehicle instance's affairs in order, as it were, before getting garbage-collected?

P.S.
`ObjectSpace#count_objects` is no a viable option, as even the Ruby docs are up front about.

Comment: Interesting blog post about this very topic I read awhile back: http://blog.maxaller.name/2009/12/destructors-in-ruby-not-quite/

Comment: Your code does not return '1' but a NoMethodError (the methods being instance methods).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, they will never be garbage collected, as you are holding a reference in `@@all_instances`. You could use a finalizer to get the result you want:

```
class Vehicle
  class << self
    attr_accessor :count
    def finalize(id)
      @count -= 1
    end

    def all #returns an array of all Vehicle objects
      ObjectSpace.each_object(Vehicle).to_a
    end
  end
  Vehicle.count ||= 0

  def initialize
    Vehicle.count += 1
    ObjectSpace.define_finalizer(self, Vehicle.method(:finalize))
  end
end

100.times{Vehicle.new}
p Vehicle.count  # => 100
ObjectSpace.garbage_collect
p Vehicle.count  # => 1, not sure why
p Vehicle.all    # => [#<Vehicle:0x0000010208e730>]
```

If you run this code, you will see that it "works", except that there remains one Vehicle that is not garbage collected. I'm not sure why that is.

Your `count` method could be also defined more simply by returning `ObjectSpace.each_object(Vehicle).count`

Finally, if you really want to maintain a list of existing Vehicles, you need to store their ID and use `ObjectSpace._id2ref`:

```
require 'set'

class Vehicle
  class << self
    def finalize(id)
      @ids.delete(id)
    end

    def register(obj)
      @ids ||= Set.new
      @ids << obj.object_id
      ObjectSpace.define_finalizer(obj, method(:finalize))
    end

    def all #returns an array of all Vehicle objects
      @ids.map{|id| ObjectSpace._id2ref(id)}
    end

    def count
      @ids.size
    end
  end

  def initialize
    Vehicle.register(self)
  end
end
```

Comment: While reading about Ruby finalizers, I found this good [article](http://www.mikeperham.com/2010/02/24/the-trouble-with-ruby-finalizers/), which describes a problem with your code (this can actually explain that mystical 1 instance remaining): one problem with your `define_finalizer` method is that the finalizer proc is a closure which holds a reference to it’s `self`, thus making it impossible for the image object to ever be garbage collected.

Comment: @GregoryGoltsov: Actually, I was careful about this. The finalizer proc is `Vehicle.method(:finalize)`, it only holds a reference to the class `Vehicle`.

Answer (score 3):

What you almost certainly want here is the [WeakRef](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/weakref/rdoc/index.html) class from the standard library.  That handles all the details of object tracking and management without blocking reference counting.

Using a WeakRef that points to the object in your tracking you can delegate the whole finalization work to the library, and simplify your own life.  (You may need to flush dead items from the arrays, but that is easily enough wrapped in your parent class.)

eg:

```
def all_instances
   # this will vacuum out the dead references and return the remainder.
   @@weakrefs_to_vehicles = @@weakrefs_to_vehicles.select(&:weakref_alive?)
end

def total_vehicles
   all_instances.count
end
```