# How to count instances of class without counting reassignment?

Tags: ruby, class, methods, instances

I am working on class methods.

I am trying to count the number of created instances of a class. I am able to do this by creating a counter variable in the `initialize` method.

The problem arises when I reassign the variable originally assigned to one class instance. Because the `initialize` method is called twice, it does not recognize that the variable is simply being reassigned to another class instance.

```
class Ticket
    attr_accessor :price
    attr_reader :event, :venue

    @@count = 0
    @@tickets = {}

    def initialize(event, venue)
        @event = event
        @venue = venue

        @@count += 1
    end

    def self.count
        @@count 
    end
end

a = Ticket.new("Michael Buble", "Staples")

a = Ticket.new("Frank Sinatra", "Madison Square Garden")

puts "Ticket count of #{Ticket.count}"
```

When I run the above code in IRB, it gives me a `Ticket count of 2` (as expected). How do I change my code so that it recognizes the overwrite?

NOTE: I know that this question has been asked before for Objective C, but the reassignment aspect of the question adds a different element to the problem. Let me know otherwise.

Comment: You could override "new" class method for Class object and increment the instance counter only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the real world you wouldn't be counting instances in memory, you'd be asking a database how many exist. You need to think in terms of a database.

Your use of `a` to repeatedly contain the Ticket instance is wrong. You should be using an Array, Hash or Set to maintain the list, then ask the container how many exist:

```
require 'set'

class Ticket
  attr_accessor :price
  attr_reader :event, :venue

  @@tickets = Set.new

  def initialize(event, venue)
    @event = event
    @venue = venue

    @@tickets << self
  end

  def delete
    @@tickets.delete(self)
  end

  def self.count
    @@tickets.size
  end

end

a = Ticket.new("Michael Buble", "Staples")
b = Ticket.new("Frank Sinatra", "Madison Square Garden")

puts "Ticket count of #{Ticket::count}"
b.delete
puts "Ticket count of #{Ticket::count}"
```

You can build this out by adding ways to retrieve a particular instance from `@@tickets`, add a `to_s` so you can list them, but, in the end, you'll want to use a real database. If your code were to crash for any reason, your entire list of tickets would disappear, which would be unacceptable in real life.

Comment: Exactly. The above code still returns a count of 3 if you reassign `a` without first destroying the Ticket assigned to `a`. You would have to enforce checking for a current value before reassignment in your code. This is a valuable lesson for those of us who are newer users: If it's THIS complicated to implement, there's probably a reason there is not a simple Ruby method for it. i.e. There are other best practices like you have pointed out.

Comment: As long as there is a reference to an instance of an object it will remain in memory. Once all references are removed Ruby will garbage-collect the instance and it will no longer exist. Garbage collection doesn't occur immediately. It being in memory means nothing if you can't retrieve it.

Answer (score 7):

```
ObjectSpace.each_object(Ticket).count
```

Will give you the count of object currently in memory. On testing in IRB I find it runs into the problem you describe, objects persist in memory even though you have assigned a new one to the variable. Technically the object still exists, even though you assign a new instance to the variable "a".

See this article: [Deleting an object in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406419/deleting-an-object-in-ruby) The answers have plenty of info about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want to count live instances of the `Ticket` class (for reasons I cannot fathom), @Beartech has the right idea:

```
class Ticket
  attr_reader :event, :venue

  def initialize(event, venue)
    @event = event
    @venue = venue
  end   

  def self.count_live_instances
    ObjectSpace.garbage_collect
    ObjectSpace.each_object(self).to_a.size
  end
end

a = Ticket.new("Michael Buble", "Staples")
b = Ticket.new("Cher", "Canadian Tire Center")
a = Ticket.new("Frank Sinatra", "Madison Square Garden")

puts "Ticket instances count = #{Ticket.count_live_instances}" # => 2
```

It is essential to garbage-collect before invoking [`ObjectSpace#each_object`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/ObjectSpace.html#method-c-each_object).  If you are skeptical, insert `p ObjectSpace.each_object(self).to_a.size` as the first line of `self.count_live_instances`.  It will print `3`.

(There is also a method [`ObjectSpace#count_objects`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/ObjectSpace.html#method-c-count_objects).  This method returns a hash like this one: `{:TOTAL=>56139,..., :T_ARRAY=>3139,..., :T_ICLASS=>32}`.  Unfortunately, the keys are "object types"; you won't find `:TICKET` among them.)

Answer (score 0):

`class Gs
def self.method1
    code...
end
def self.method2
    code...
end
def self.method3
     code... 
end
end
Gs.new
p Gs.singleton_methods.count`

The `Gs.singleton_methods.count` will print `3` 
it will count the singleton methods,if we use the `self` keyword or 
classname.method name..